# "Invalid Qualifier" when writing to cell from string array

Tags: vba, excel

I have a simple macro to set some common headers and formatting:

```
Dim colString(1 To 17, 1 To 2) As String
Dim i As Integer

colString(1, 1) = "NA" ' Column header
colString(1, 2) = "23" ' Column background color index
colString(2, 1) = "NB"
colString(2, 2) = "1"

' etc, until (17, 2)

For i = 1 To 17
    With Cells(1, i)
        .Value = colString(i, 1).Value
        .Interior.ColorIndex = CInt(colString(i, 2))
        .Font.Color = vbWhite
        '.Font.Bold
    End With
Next i
```

I get an error at this line:

```
 .Value = colString(i, 1).Value
```

The error reads "invalid qualifier" with "colString" highlighted.

I don't understand why I get this error, or how to change it. Since I'm iterating over a single row, using Cells seems like the easiest route? Google, MrExcel and SO turns up nothing.

Comment: Remove the `.Value` - `colString` is an array, not an object.

Comment: It's always the simple oversights... sigh. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Rory or vsoraas, can you add an answer and accept?  That helps everyone in some way.

Comment: @Rory if you post the answer, I'll give you a checkmark. Until then, I've posted one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array is typed as String, not any sort of Object, so its items don't have properties or methods. You therefore need to remove the `.Value` (and use it as you did in the following line):

```
With Cells(1, i)
    .Value = colString(i, 1)
    .Interior.ColorIndex = CInt(colString(i, 2))
    .Font.Color = vbWhite
    '.Font.Bold
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 .Value = colString(i, 1)
```

Arrays cannot take .Value.